# using functions in COUNTIF criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

Do you know of any documentation of Excel regarding specifying complex criteria for `COUNTIF` - e.g. conditions using functions, referring to neighbor cells, etc.

E.g. something like (this one doesn't work)

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A1000;   "OR(ISTEXT(A1); ISNUMBER(B1)")
```

Comment: What have you researched? `COUNTIF` doesn't allow multiple criteria. Did you look at the [`COUNTIFS` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)?

Comment: I may be wrong, but `COUNTIFS` doesn't seem to provide anything more than `COUNTIF` for functions like `ISTEXT`, `ISNUMBER`, etc. At least the linked document doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex criteria are not available for **COUNTIF(S)**, just the basic comparisons (=,<>,<,>,<=,>=). To do more complex comparisons, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` and `--` (which converts True to 1 and False to 0)

For example, to count where there is text in **A**, and a corresponding number in **B**, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISTEXT(A1:A1000)),--(ISNUMBER(B1:B1000)))
```