# DCOUNT With Function in Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of data in Excel with each row possessing multiple columns. For the sake of simplicity, let's call them A and B. I want to count the rows wherein which the sum of A and B is less than integer X. Normally, I would set up two rows for this criteria: the top would have the label for the column, and the bottom would have the criteria itself.

```
----
|A |
----
|<X|
----
```

That works just fine, but if I do something like this, the DCOUNT function just returns 0, which is an incorrect answer:

```
-------
|A + B|
-------
|<X   |
-------
```

Obviously there is something incorrect with the `A + B` syntax, but I can't figure it out. None of the examples for DCOUNT I have found demonstrate the use of functions in criteria. I also saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/684741/using-functions-in-countif-criteria), but it doesn't seem to be entirely relevant.

I am also aware that it would be possible to make an additional column with the sum of A and B and use that for the criteria, but that seems unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: Are you attached to `DCOUNT`? Or are you open to solutions that use other functions?

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, I'd prefer to use DCOUNT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in columns A and B, put your criteria in, say, D1 and D2. D1 must contain a header that is not present in your headers, and D2 is your formula. D2 contains this formula:

```
=A2+B2<X
```

and your `DCOUNT()` looks like this:

```
=DCOUNT(A:B,1,D1:D2)
```